# echo $row php script shows it's working in returned uri but field doesn't get pulled from sqlite3 db

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a link that when it is clicked it populates a form with all the rows from a sqlite3 db. here is the link:

```
    <a href="update_aar.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &date=<?php echo $row['Date'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &app_prod=<?php echo $row['app_prod'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &change=<?php echo $row['change'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &business_unit=<?php echo $row['business_unit'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &team_resolved=<?php echo $row['team_resolved'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &operator_view_url=<?php echo $row['operator_view_url'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &reported_by=<?php echo $row['reported_by'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &gets_owner=<?php echo $row['gets_owner'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &gets_sro=<?php echo $row['gets_sro'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &impact=<?php echo $row['impact'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &state=<?php echo $row['state'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &action_req=<?php echo $row['action_req'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &label=<?php echo $row['label'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &responsible_area=<?php echo $row['responsible_area'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &mttd=<?php echo $row['mttd'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &mttr=<?php echo $row['mttr'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &pre_co=<?php echo $row['pre_co'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &co_planning=<?php echo $row['co_planning'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &co_execution=<?php echo $row['co_execution'];?>
                                                                                                                                                                     
                                &co_verification=<?php echo $row['co_verification'];?>" 
                                target="_blank" ><?php echo $row['ID'];?></a>
```

all of the fields populate the form correctly except the label field. The URI shows that it is pulling the data correctly too, here is an example from the URI when you click the link:

&label=B3F0066IBM%20LDAP%20DigiCert%

When I use the form to query by ID, the information populates the form correctly.
Does anyone have any ideas as to why this link wouldn't work?

Comment: By including line breaks in the HTML, I’m guessing that’s how the `%20` is getting into the URL. I would build the URL, or at least the query portion, in [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: the %20's are spaces in the db string. what should be populating the form is B3F0066IBM LDAP DigiCert

Comment: See [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode) and potentially [`urldecode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)